# usage of namespace, unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++

```
test.cpp


enum {

  ERR_FILE_ACCESS       = 1,
  ERR_WHATEVER
};

enum ERR : unsigned int {

  ERR_FILE_ACCESS     = 5,
  ERR_FILE_FORMAT     = 6
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  return 0;
}
```

of course fails with redefinition of enumerator 'ERR_FILE_ACCESS'.
but:

```
test2.cpp

enum {

  ERR_FILE_ACCESS       = 1,
  ERR_FILE_FORMAT,
  ERR_WHATEVER
};

namespace Internal {

  enum ERR : unsigned int {

    ERR_FILE_ACCESS     = 5,
    ERR_FILE_FORMAT     = 6
  };
}
using namespace Internal;

int main(int, char**)
{
  return 0;
}
```

does compile successfully.

I'm surprised/confused, why does the namespace - after `using namespace Internal;`- prevent the name collision?

Comment: Because then the symbols are in different namespaces.

Comment: [using directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives) (that's the term you are looking for) in C++ don't mean quite the same as `import Internal.*` one might see in many other languages. And most importantly, in C++, they don't add any declarations anywhere. Instead they just allow them to be found... sometimes.

Comment: but with 'using namespace' I import them into the global namespace, no?

Comment: No you don't "import" them, you simply make the namespace available for symbol lookup.  If the symbol is found before it needs to look in the namespace then there's no conflict.

Comment: Aah, that explains my observation, as long as I not use one of the "conflicting" symbols everything is fine, but (in this example) when I try to use 'ERR_FILE_ACCESS' I get ambiguous error.

Comment: You nailed it, Albert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the namespace - after `using namespace Internal;`- prevent the name collision?

Because in the second case, the **enumerators live in different namespaces and  *using directive* does not actually add the names to the declarative region**(which is global scope/namespace in this example) **in which it appears.**

This can be seen from [using directive's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives):

> Using-directive **does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears** (unlike the using-declaration), and **thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.**

---

This behavior is not dangerous.
As long as you don't use one of the "conflicting" symbols(which are the enumerators here), everything is fine, but when you try to use one of them, you'll get the "symbol is ambiguous" error.

Comment: Really important distinction: `using-directive` vs. `using-declaration`. `using Internal::ERR::ERR_FILE_ACCESS;` would give a compile error!

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, as a using-declaration "adds" names in the declarative region.